# Parsley Remote and Additional Parameters

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I am trying to use the remote validator with Parsley and I can't seem to send additional data with the request.  The field in question is an email field, and I want to send it to the server to see if the email address is 'available'.  In addition, I need to send an id parameter which the server requires.  The id parameter is embedded in my form in the 'host' field.

So, I have tried using the Parsley DOM API as follows:

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="15" id="email" name='email'
            data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-type-message="Must be a valid email format"
            data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="Email is required"
            data-parsley-remote="/invitation/allowed"
            data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "get", "data" : { "id": function() {return $("#host").val(); } }}'>
```

In the final line of the API config I have tried various combinations to get the value of the host field into my URL.  These include escaping the quotes in the function; and proving 'host' (or '#host') as the value of the id property.  In each case I can get only my email address passed in the URL.

Note that I can pass a literal no problems (for example `{ "id": "TestTest" }`).

I have also tried using javascript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/parsley.remote.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$('#employee-form').parsley({})</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#email').parsley().addConstraint('remote',
    {
        url: '/invitation/allowed',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            id: function () { return $('#host').val() }
        }
    })
</script>
```

When I do this I have two problems: the id is not set in the URL, and also the base url is incorrect - it calls the address of the current page (not /invitation/allowed).

This question, which was asked a few hours ago, is similar: [Remote validation for a field which depends on others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675442/remote-validation-for-a-field-which-depends-on-others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same trouble, wanting to pass an API key with each request, so I submitted a pull request with the feature. I think it'll be officially released very soon, see pull request here:

https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/pull/645

Comment: Thanks jsnandrew, I did see that request.  Looks like it will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Parsley [pull request #645](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/pull/645) does not seem to address the problem fully. It allows you to specify ajax options in the `addAsyncValidator()` call, but those options are evaluated at the time of the call, not when the ajax request is made (e.g. the ajax  `data` option is filled once on page load.)  So any other form values passed in the request are not "live" they are whatever the values were at the time `addAsyncValidator()` was called.  It seems we need to be able to specify a function for the `data` parameter.  I made a small tweak to the Parsley.js code that allows that:

Existing code in `validateString`:

```
  // Merge options passed in from the function with the ones in the attribute
  var remoteOptions = $.extend(true, options.options || {}, Parsley.asyncValidators[validator].options);
```

Then right after that my addition:

```
  if (typeof remoteOptions.data === 'function') {
      remoteOptions.data = remoteOptions.data();
  }
```

So then in your code:

```
    <input type="text" ... id="host" data-parsley-remote="" data-parsley-remote-validator="invitation" />
    <input type="text" ... id="email" data-parsley-remote="" data-parsley-remote-validator="invitation" />

    <script>
    window.Parsley.addAsyncValidator(
        'invitation',
        function (xhr) {
            return xhr.status == 200;
        },
        '/invitation/allowed',
        {
            data: function () {
                return {
                    host: $('#host').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val();
                };
            }
        }
    );
    </script>
```

I don't see any other way of doing it except destroy the async validator and re-create it every time relevant form values change.

Note two things: (1) The function *replaces* the data not adds to it, and (2) it seems you would need to do the async validation if *any* of the relevant inputs change.