# Parsley.js isValid() returns null using custom validator

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, parsley.js

I am using parsley.js(2.8.1) custom validator to check if input code already exists on server.
Everything works fine but `parsley().isValid()` and `parsley().validate()` returns `null` when submit.

Removing custom validator works fine but I am unable to check existed code on the server from client side.

```
     <form id="product-form">
   [....]
   <input id="product-code"
    data-parsley-code="check-code" data-parsley-length="[3,32]"
    type="text" class="form-control" required>
   [....]
   </form>

   <script>
    $(function(){
        let formInstance = $('#product-form');
        formInstance.parsley();
        Parsley.addValidator('code', {
            validateString: function(value, requirement) {
                let xhr = $.post('/product/' + requirement + '/' + value);
                return xhr.then(function (json) {
                    if (!json.status) {
                        return $.Deferred().reject(json.message)
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {en: 'Failed to check product code.'}
        });

        formInstance.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          console.log(formInstance.parsley().validate());  // returns null
          console.log(formInstance.parsley().isValid()); // returns null
       if (formInstance.parsley().isValid())) {
           [.....]
       }
   }
    [.....]
    </script>
```

I would like to check and submit form and do the ajax stuff.

Answer (score 0):

### Option1:

Because your code works with promises, move to `whenValidate`, from [documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#remote-custom):

> The validate({group, force}) method that returns a boolean or null
>   will always return null due to remote validation always returning open
>   promises.

Pay attention that your handler is missing a return statement in case of true.

Please read the inside implementation of [parsley.remote.js](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/remote.html) for a reference (if its still to complicate, move to option2)

### Option2:

You can add the `parsley.remote.js` js file into your project and then make use of the `addAsyncValidator`

Good example of the remote usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42350874/6844481) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41172571/6844481).

Comment: can you pls edit your question based on what you updated? cause I can't see it return any true or false

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: too complex to understand.